# How to do a function at the same time with the loop?

Tags: python

I am trying to run the turtle that can move left and right by arrow key, and at the same time two object call harm and benefit fall down from top of the screen. However, I can not do both of them at the same time

I running by repl.it.

```
def run():
   screen.onkey(left,"Left")
   screen.onkey(right,"Right")
   while True:
     benefit()
     harm()  
run()
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you have a specific issue that you can succinctly explain with examples?

Comment: share a link to ur repl

Comment: to run two functions at the same time,you can use threading or multiprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what framework you're using to drive your app, but most likely you want to split what's going on to single-frame actions. Find how to execute something each time a new frame is displayed and in that code execute something that moves your objects just a bit. For falling objects you can do that by either updating the `y` coordinate by some constant, or by `(this_frame_time - last_frame_time) * speed` to keep the movement smooth.